# Emulator Crahses after no input

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I am very new to Java and Android Apps, and i am creating a simple Calculator and all is going well but i discovered a problem and that is when i just press for example Multiply with no numbers in place my emulator will crash, i missing some sort of cod in my listener but cant find out what and where it goes here is my MainActivity,Java:

```
    package com.firstprogram;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.text.InputType;
    import android.util.TypedValue;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout layout1;
    LinearLayout buttonLayout;
    EditText number1text;
    EditText number2text;
    Button   multiplyButton;
    Button divideButton;
    Button addButton;
    Button subButton;
    TextView answerText;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        layout1 = new LinearLayout (this);
        buttonLayout = new LinearLayout (this);
        number1text = new EditText (this);
        number2text = new EditText (this);
        multiplyButton = new Button (this);
        divideButton = new Button (this);
        addButton = new Button (this);
        subButton = new Button (this);
        answerText = new TextView (this);

        answerText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,28);

        layout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        buttonLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        buttonLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        number1text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        number2text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

        answerText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        answerText.setText("0");
        multiplyButton.setText("X");
        divideButton.setText("/");
        addButton.setText("+");
        subButton.setText("-");

        multiplyButton.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) multiplyClicked);
        divideButton.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) divideClicked);
        addButton.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) addClicked);
        subButton.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) subClicked);

        buttonLayout.addView(multiplyButton);
        buttonLayout.addView(divideButton);
        buttonLayout.addView(addButton);
        buttonLayout.addView(subButton);

        layout1.addView(number1text);
        layout1.addView(number2text);
        layout1.addView(buttonLayout);
        layout1.addView(answerText);


        setContentView(layout1);  

        number1text.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500,50));
        number2text.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500,50));
        multiplyButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50,50));
        divideButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50,50));
        addButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50,50));
        subButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50,50));
    }

    private View.OnClickListener multiplyClicked = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick (View v){
            String firstString = number1text.getText().toString();
            String secondString = number2text.getText().toString();
            double firstNumber = Double.parseDouble(firstString);
            double secondNumber = Double.parseDouble(secondString);
            double result = firstNumber * secondNumber;
            String resultString = String.valueOf(result);
            answerText.setText(resultString);
        }
    };

 private View.OnClickListener divideClicked = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick (View v){
            String firstString = number1text.getText().toString();
            String secondString = number2text.getText().toString();
            double firstNumber = Double.parseDouble(firstString);
            double secondNumber = Double.parseDouble(secondString);
            if(secondNumber!=0) {
            double result = firstNumber / secondNumber;
            String resultString = String.valueOf(result);
            answerText.setText(resultString);
            }
        }
    };

 private View.OnClickListener addClicked = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick (View v){
            String firstString = number1text.getText().toString();
            String secondString = number2text.getText().toString();
            double firstNumber = Double.parseDouble(firstString);
            double secondNumber = Double.parseDouble(secondString);
            double result = firstNumber + secondNumber;
            String resultString = String.valueOf(result);
            answerText.setText(resultString);
        }
    };

private View.OnClickListener subClicked = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick (View v){
            String firstString = number1text.getText().toString();
            String secondString = number2text.getText().toString();
            double firstNumber = Double.parseDouble(firstString);
            double secondNumber = Double.parseDouble(secondString);
            double result = firstNumber - secondNumber;
            String resultString = String.valueOf(result);
            answerText.setText(resultString);
        }
    };



}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
08-23 07:15:06.241: D/gralloc_goldfish(792): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-23 07:15:15.631: D/dalvikvm(792): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 257K, 14% free 2762K/3176K, paused 50ms, total 63ms
08-23 07:20:06.893: D/gralloc_goldfish(850): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-23 07:21:21.171: I/Choreographer(850): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-23 07:21:30.881: I/Choreographer(850): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-23 07:23:39.641: D/gralloc_goldfish(893): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-23 07:29:47.051: I/Choreographer(893): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-23 07:37:02.152: I/Choreographer(893): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-23 07:38:16.154: D/gralloc_goldfish(936): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-23 07:51:40.516: I/Choreographer(936): Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-23 07:53:47.001: I/Choreographer(936): Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-23 08:22:32.431: I/Choreographer(936): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-23 08:36:53.827: I/Choreographer(936): Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-23 08:51:51.864: I/Choreographer(936): Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-23 08:56:47.101: I/Choreographer(936): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-23 08:57:40.044: I/Choreographer(936): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-23 09:07:14.461: I/Choreographer(936): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-23 09:08:47.069: I/Choreographer(936): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-23 09:14:26.301: D/gralloc_goldfish(1109): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-23 09:14:31.151: D/AndroidRuntime(1109): Shutting down VM
08-23 09:14:31.151: W/dalvikvm(1109): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
08-23 09:14:31.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1109): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-23 09:14:31.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1109): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
08-23 09:14:31.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
08-23 09:14:31.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:248)
08-23 09:14:31.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
08-23 09:14:31.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at com.firstprogram.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:93)
08-23 09:14:31.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
08-23 09:14:31.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
08-23 09:14:31.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
08-23 09:14:31.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-23 09:14:31.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-23 09:14:31.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-23 09:14:31.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 09:14:31.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-23 09:14:31.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-23 09:14:31.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-23 09:14:31.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 09:14:31.321: D/dalvikvm(1109): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 243K, 13% free 2776K/3176K, paused 57ms, total 73ms
08-23 09:14:51.461: D/gralloc_goldfish(1152): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-23 09:21:59.242: I/Choreographer(1152): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-23 09:27:10.061: I/Choreographer(1152): Skipped 69 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-23 09:42:37.441: D/gralloc_goldfish(1211): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-23 09:48:27.291: D/gralloc_goldfish(1258): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-23 09:48:34.741: D/dalvikvm(1258): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 240K, 13% free 2779K/3176K, paused 68ms, total 76ms
08-23 09:51:57.135: I/Choreographer(1258): Skipped 97 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-23 09:59:16.411: I/Choreographer(1258): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-23 09:59:21.872: D/AndroidRuntime(1258): Shutting down VM
08-23 09:59:21.872: W/dalvikvm(1258): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
08-23 09:59:21.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1258): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-23 09:59:21.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1258): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
08-23 09:59:21.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
08-23 09:59:21.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:248)
08-23 09:59:21.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
08-23 09:59:21.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at com.firstprogram.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:91)
08-23 09:59:21.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
08-23 09:59:21.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
08-23 09:59:21.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
08-23 09:59:21.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-23 09:59:21.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-23 09:59:21.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-23 09:59:21.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 09:59:21.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-23 09:59:21.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-23 09:59:21.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-23 09:59:21.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 09:59:25.653: I/Process(1258): Sending signal. PID: 1258 SIG: 9
08-23 09:59:51.091: D/gralloc_goldfish(1314): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-23 09:59:57.921: D/AndroidRuntime(1314): Shutting down VM
08-23 09:59:57.921: W/dalvikvm(1314): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
08-23 09:59:58.061: D/dalvikvm(1314): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 241K, 13% free 2778K/3176K, paused 62ms, total 70ms
08-23 09:59:58.072: E/AndroidRuntime(1314): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-23 09:59:58.072: E/AndroidRuntime(1314): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
08-23 09:59:58.072: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
08-23 09:59:58.072: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:248)
08-23 09:59:58.072: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
08-23 09:59:58.072: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at com.firstprogram.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:92)
08-23 09:59:58.072: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
08-23 09:59:58.072: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
08-23 09:59:58.072: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
08-23 09:59:58.072: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-23 09:59:58.072: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-23 09:59:58.072: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-23 09:59:58.072: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 09:59:58.072: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-23 09:59:58.072: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-23 09:59:58.072: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-23 09:59:58.072: E/AndroidRuntime(1314):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 10:00:00.761: I/Process(1314): Sending signal. PID: 1314 SIG: 9
08-23 10:01:31.132: D/gralloc_goldfish(1365): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-23 10:01:47.221: D/dalvikvm(1365): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 242K, 13% free 2777K/3176K, paused 77ms, total 85ms
08-23 10:01:47.221: D/AndroidRuntime(1365): Shutting down VM
08-23 10:01:47.232: W/dalvikvm(1365): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
08-23 10:01:47.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1365): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-23 10:01:47.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1365): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
08-23 10:01:47.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
08-23 10:01:47.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:248)
08-23 10:01:47.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
08-23 10:01:47.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at com.firstprogram.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:92)
08-23 10:01:47.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
08-23 10:01:47.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
08-23 10:01:47.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
08-23 10:01:47.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-23 10:01:47.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-23 10:01:47.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-23 10:01:47.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 10:01:47.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-23 10:01:47.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-23 10:01:47.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-23 10:01:47.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 10:01:49.873: I/Process(1365): Sending signal. PID: 1365 SIG: 9
```

Comment: You need to post the output from LogCat here.

Comment: Your app crashes or the whole emulator (window goes away)?

Comment: i have added the LogCat and also just the app crashes

Answer (score 4):

In your listener `onClick`, you're grabbing the text in `number1text` and `number2text` and trying to convert them to `Double`s. If those are empty (or the user's typed in something like "hello, there!"), the system can't convert the strings into numbers, and you'll get a `NumberFormatException`. That's almost certainly what's happening here, though the output from LogCat should specify.

You need to wrap all of your `parseDouble` calls in `try...catch` blocks and take appropriate action (like popping up a toast saying "I can't do that, Dave." and then not proceeding).

Answer (score 1):

You could simply put `if` statements in each of your button listeners, which checks that numbers have been given. If the string is "" then parseDouble will fail, which is why you're getting the error.

For example:

```
private View.OnClickListener multiplyClicked = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick (View v){
        String firstString = number1text.getText().toString();
        String secondString = number2text.getText().toString();

        if (firstString != NULL && secondString != NULL) { // Checks strings aren't null
            double firstNumber = Double.parseDouble(firstString);
            double secondNumber = Double.parseDouble(secondString);
            double result = firstNumber * secondNumber;
            String resultString = String.valueOf(result);
            answerText.setText(resultString);
        } else {
            // Do something eg. print "Can't do that!"
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: That would solve the immediate problem, but not if someone enters a non-empty string that still isn't a valid number (something like `1.1.1.1` is possible even with a numeric-only keypad). Catching the `NumberFormatException` is more reliable.

Comment: Yes you're right, I didn't think of that case. Try/catch is much better, as your answer suggested

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
```

That is where the problem is.

Before you multiply or do any operation, you need to check whether the input is null or empty and may be also check whether it's a number or not(even though a user will only be able to enter numbers)